# InDesign Server - Exporting PDF with embedded transparent TIFF images

Tags: transparency, tiff, indesign-server

I'm trying to export a PDF with embedded transparent TIFF images. These images have extremely large dimensions. During the embed process, they are shrunk down to fit in the placeholder frames within the target InDesign file. Because of the dramatic decrease in size, when I then export a PDF from the InDesign file I get a halo affect from the anti-aliasing around the edges of the embedded images. I've had some luck reducing the size of the halo by telling InDesign to not down-sample, but I haven't been able to eliminate it. Does anyone know a way to get rid of this artifact?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Better asked on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear, but this is about scripting for InDesign server. Server uses javascript to control various commands, and I'm trying to determine a way to solve my problem using it.